# In a list of dicts, flag a dict if combination of key/value pairs is identical in another dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, defaultdict

I have a list of dictionaries with the keys `street`, `number` and `some_flag`.

My goal is to search the dicts for duplicates in the keys `street` and `number`. If for two or more dicts these two key/value pairs are identical, I want to assign the value 1 to their `some_flag` key.

Please see reproducible example below.

### Starting list of dictionaries:

```
a = [
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '1', 'some_flag': 0},
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '3', 'some_flag': 0},
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '4', 'some_flag': 0}, # duplicate street / number keys
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '4', 'some_flag': 0}, # duplicate street / number keys
    {'street': 'apple tree rd.', 'number': '3', 'some_flag': 0},
]
```

### Expected output:

```
a_checked = [
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '1', 'some_flag': 0},
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '3', 'some_flag': 0},
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '4', 'some_flag': 1}, # duplicate street / number keys
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '4', 'some_flag': 1}, # duplicate street / number keys
    {'street': 'apple tree rd.', 'number': '3', 'some_flag': 0},
]
```

### My best effort:

The code I've got so far is derived from Aarons answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621915/find-duplicates-in-python-list-of-dictionaries)) and the community wiki's answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/how-do-i-find-the-duplicates-in-a-list-and-create-another-list-with-them))

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

items = defaultdict(list) # create defaultdict 

for row in a:
    items[row['street']].append(row['number'])  # make a list of 'number' values for each 'street' key


for key in items.keys():
    if checkIfDuplicates(items[key]):  #if there is more than one 'number' --> function definition see below  
        duplicate_dict = {}
        duplicate_dict['numbers'] =  [item for item, count in Counter(items[key]).items() if count > 1] # storing duplicate numbers in dict
        duplicate_dict['street'] = key # storing street name in same dict
```

Function to check if given list contains any duplicates (from [here](https://thispointer.com/python-3-ways-to-check-if-there-are-duplicates-in-a-list/)):

```
def checkIfDuplicates(listOfElems): 
    if len(listOfElems) == len(set(listOfElems)):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

**current output:**

```
print(duplicate_dict)
{'numbers': ['4'], 'street': 'ocean drive'}
```

With my approach, I would now have to match the `duplicate_dict` with the original list `a`, which doesn't seem very efficient.

Are there more direct ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `dict.setdefault` to first store a dict of lists (where the keys are "street" and "number") and then iterate over the values of this dictionary to check if multiple dicts have the same "street" and "number" and modify "some_flag" of those that are multiple:

```
tmp = {}
for d in a:
    tmp.setdefault((d['street'], d['number']), []).append(d)
out = []
for v in tmp.values():
    if len(v) > 1:
        for d in v:
            d['some_flag'] = 1
    out.extend(v)
```

Output:

```
[{'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '1', 'some_flag': 0},
 {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '3', 'some_flag': 0},
 {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '4', 'some_flag': 1},
 {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '4', 'some_flag': 1},
 {'street': 'apple tree rd.', 'number': '3', 'some_flag': 0}]
```

Answer (score 2):

If the list of dictionaries is not sorted, then we'd have to check every possible pair of elements for equality, which would take `O(n^2)` time.
But if the list is sorted, then we could check each element with its next element, if they weren't equal, then there is no point checking that element with the following elements. On the other hand, if they were equal, we continue checking with the next one, and so on.

```
def is_duplicate(d_1, d_2):
    return d_1['street'] == d_2['street'] and d_1['number'] == d_2['number']


def set_duplicate(d_1, d_2):
    d_1['some_flag'] = 1
    d_2['some_flag'] = 1

a = sorted(a, key=lambda k: (k['street'].lower(), k['number']))

cur_index = 0
while cur_index < len(a):

    next_index = cur_index + 1
    while next_index < len(a) and is_duplicate(a[cur_index], a[next_index]):
        set_duplicate(a[cur_index], a[next_index])
        next_index += 1

    cur_index += 1

print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply can be done by:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Your code
a = [
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '1', 'some_flag': 0},
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '3', 'some_flag': 0},
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '4', 'some_flag': 0}, # duplicate street / number keys
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '4', 'some_flag': 0}, # duplicate street / number keys
    {'street': 'apple tree rd.', 'number': '3', 'some_flag': 0},
]
# My code
data = pd.DataFrame(a)
data["some_flag"]= np.where(data.duplicated(keep=False), 1, data["some_flag"])
data
```

##### Output

|  | street | number | some_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ocean drive | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | ocean drive | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | ocean drive | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | ocean drive | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | apple tree rd. | 3 | 0 |

If you are interested in having a dictionary instead of the dataframe, you can try changing the dataframe to dictionary using `to_dict` function:

```py
data.to_dict(orient="list")
```

which results in :

```
{'number': ['1', '3', '4', '4', '3'],
 'some_flag': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
 'street': ['ocean drive',
  'ocean drive',
  'ocean drive',
  'ocean drive',
  'apple tree rd.']}
```

##### Explanation

Using `duplicated` function on a dataframe and assigning `False` to the `keep` parameter, you can find the duplicated rows. Then using `where` which is a numpy function, you can assign a value to an array based on a logical statement.

Comment: thanks you for sharing your approach but I needed the result to be in the format as I wrote in question.

Comment: Same format! Both dictionary and dataframe!

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this without pandas with a little more code e.g. like this:

```
import copy

a = [
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '1', 'some_flag': 0},
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '3', 'some_flag': 0},
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '4', 'some_flag': 0}, # duplicate street / number keys
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '4', 'some_flag': 0}, # duplicate street / number keys
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '4', 'some_flag': 0},  # duplicate street / number keys
    {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '4', 'some_flag': 0},  # duplicate street / number keys
    {'street': 'apple tree rd.', 'number': '3', 'some_flag': 0},
]

result = copy.deepcopy(a) #duplicate a to not override your input

last_entry = ""

for entry in result:
    if last_entry == "": #skip first iteration to have two entries to compare
        last_entry = entry 
        continue
    if last_entry["street"] == entry["street"] and last_entry["number"] == entry["number"]:
        last_entry["some_flag"] = 1 
        entry["some_flag"] = 1
    last_entry = entry

print(result)
```

Comment: `result = a` does not copy the original list, but instead just makes a new reference to it. (The concept is called cloning in Java). see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it

Comment: You're checking each item with its next one, but I think OP should note that if the list of dictionaries is not sorted by their street and number values, this approach would need a sorting step.

Comment: You are absolutely correct with my copy issue.  Fixed that.
Expected the array to be sorted like in the question. Maybe stick to another solution, than mine

Comment: Or we just add the sorting solution from your post ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
du = {}
for d in a:
    new_key = d['street'] + "_" + d['number']
    if new_key in du.keys():
        du[new_key] = du[new_key] + 1
    else:
        du[new_key] = 1

print(du) 
# {'ocean drive_1': 1, 'ocean drive_3': 1, 'ocean drive_4': 2, 'apple tree rd._3': 1}

for k, v in du.items():
    if v > 1:
        k1 = k.split("_")[0]
        k2 = k.split("_")[1]
        for d in a:
            if d['street'] == k1 and d['number'] == k2:
                d['some_flag'] = 1
print(a)
# [{'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '1', 'some_flag': 0}, {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '3', 'some_flag': 0}, {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '4', 'some_flag': 1}, {'street': 'ocean drive', 'number': '4', 'some_flag': 1}, {'street': 'apple tree rd.', 'number': '3', 'some_flag': 0}]
```